# How to allow role based login in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using the function below I was able to add *active* flag, so that only those users who are active can login.

Now I have another flag called *role* and I wish to allow only those users with role 1 or 2 to login.

```
public function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'active' => 1,
    ];
}
```

Comment: If you managed the first part the second part should be identical. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-parameters)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```